# Having problem on select change other select option text not update

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

want to change all text of second select options with my desired text

Reason is:

i don't want to show price in my options, So i used slice and index method to altered options text and replace text after "-" charcter .. but problem is when i change first select option other select option shows PREVIOUS text not the latest text where is coming from other source (That source not in my hand i just have html page)

there are two select box first one ID is "orderform-category"
and other where prices show "#orderform-service"

here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#orderform-category').change(function() {

        $('#orderform-service option').each(function() {
            var getOption = $(this).text();
            var getPriceIndex = getOption.indexOf("—");
            console.log(getPriceIndex);
            if(getPriceIndex!==-1){
                getOption = getOption.slice(0,getPriceIndex)+"";
            }
            console.log(getOption);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Noob, difficult to understand your question. can give a example like what it is & what  output you need or JSFiddle

Comment: include a simple demo to reproduce current output

Comment: try to set value like this $(this).val(getOption);

Comment: If you want to change `text` then `$(this).text(getOption);` after `console.log(getOption);` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code you might need trigger for executing your function and it will execute when your select box value will change.

```
  $(function(){
        $('#orderform-service').change(function(){
          var data= $(this).val();
          $('#orderform-service option').each(function() {
                    var getOption = $(this).text();
                    var getPriceIndex = getOption.indexOf("—");
                    if(getPriceIndex!==-1){
                        getOption = getOption.slice(0,getPriceIndex)+"";
                    }
                    console.log(getOption);
                    $(this).text(getOption);
                });           
        });
        $('#orderform-service').trigger('change');
    });
```